# Is there a way to know if a number starts with 0 before PHP does an automatic octdec() conversion on it?

Tags: php

Consider the following in PHP:

```
$num = 011;
echo $num; // 9
```

I can get `$num` as a base 10 number like:

```
decoct($num);
```

So, you can tell PHP makes the conversion to a base 10 automatically.
What if i want to prevent unwanted octal numbers, which will convert to decimals automatically? What if both 9 and 11 were cast to (string)s and regex matched to be valid numbers?

If I had employees working on code on the back end using numbers with my API, this could be a real issue. Is there a way to test for that number with the `0` in front of it before, it's converted? Please help.

Comment: No, if it is written in the source code then it is already interpreted as an octal number. You would have to parse your source code.

Comment: This is in your source code? I thought you meant you were accepting user input. Nothing to do, except search your source for it, as @Rizier123 suggests.

Comment: It seems lame, forcing the Programmer to enter a String as an argument like with a phone number or an extension just to make sure the number doesn't automatically convert because of a typo.

Comment: User input as a Programmer working on the Source page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PHP's *source-code parser* encounters a string such as `011` *within PHP source-code,* it will interpret the resulting value as an Octal constant, as illustrated by the following one-liner:

```
php -r '$foo=011; print (int)$foo; print "\n";'
9
```

But, if the same value is presented as "a literal string," it will be interpreted *(by the runtime library, **not** by the parser),* as a base-10 number:

```
php -r '$foo="011"; print (int)$foo; print "\n";'
11
```

Any value that is presented *"to your API"* ought to arrive "as a *string,"* as in the second case, and therefore to consistently be interpreted as a base-**10** number, whether-or-not it contains a leading zero. *(Whew!! "Goody for you!")*

Comment: The octal conversion PHP uses makes numbers as arguments nearly useless. I think they should pull the zeros and have a more complicated way, other than a typo, to create octal conversions. A hexadecimal is much harder typo to create. It's absurd!

Comment: ... but, so far as I can see, the conversion is only applied by *the parser,* and therefore only to the actual source-code applied by The Intrepid Programmer.™ The *runtime* "string-to-integer conversion" logic does *not* do the same thing. *("Oopsie!")* **;-)**  So... from the OP's point-of-view, I think, "the octal-conversion" simply will not apply: *the PHP Parser* will never see these strings, and therefore will never apply its own (peculiar ...) rules to them.